# In which situation should structural dissociation theory be applied?

Tags: abnormal-psychology, stress, ptsd

In which specific situation you think is most appropriate to apply Van der Hart's SDT?

Answer (score 4):

According to a presentation given by Van Der Hart ["Structural Dissociation of the
Personality: The Key to Understanding
Chronic Traumatization and Its
Treatment"](http://www.estd.org/conferences/presentations/Onno%20van%20der%20Hart.pdf), this theory relates to the response to trauma, described further in the paper ["Trauma-related dissociation: conceptual
clarity lost and found"](http://www.onnovdhart.nl/articles/traumarelated.pdf) (Hart et al. 2004).  From the abstract:

> It postulates a common psychobiological pathway for all
>   trauma-related disorders. Trauma-related dissociation is maintained by integrative deficits
>   and phobic avoidance. This conceptualization advances diagnosis, classification, treatment
>   and research of trauma-related disorders.